# Why $(\alpha\frac{e}{t})^t e^{-\alpha}$ is an approximation for $P(X > t\alpha)$ for Poisson distribution $\frac{\alpha^ke^{k}}{k!}$?

Tags: approximation, poisson-distribution

I am reading [Section 3.4 of Algorithms, 4th Edition](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/). Page 466 is a proof of the following proposition:

> In a separate-chaining hash table with $M$ lists and $N$ keys, the probability (under Assumption J) that the number of keys in a list is within a small constant factor of $N/M$ is extremely close to 1.

The proof:

> The probability that a given list will contain exactly k keys is given by the binomial distribution
>
> $\binom{N}{k}(\frac{1}{M})^k(\frac{M-1}{M})^{N-k}$

When $N$ is large and $p=\frac{1}{M}$ is small, binomial distribution can be approximated by Poisson distribution (The book uses $\alpha$ for $\lambda$):

$\frac{\alpha^ke^{k}}{k!}$

> It follows that the probability that a list has more than $t\alpha$ keys on it is bounded by the quantity $(\alpha\frac{e}{t})^t e^{-\alpha}$.

In other words, the probability that $P(X > t\alpha)$ is bounded by the quantity $(\alpha\frac{e}{t})^t e^{-\alpha}$.

I searched the web and browsed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution. But I couldn't find a reference for the formula $(\alpha\frac{e}{t})^t e^{-\alpha}$.

Here is a candidate answer combining @Did's and @ClementC's comments:

From the background in the book, we can assume that $\alpha \geqslant 10$ and $t \geqslant 2$.

For $s > 0$, $\{X \geqslant t\alpha \} = \{sX \geqslant st\alpha\} = \{e^{sX} \geqslant e^{st\alpha}\}$, so

$P(X > t\alpha ) \leqslant P(X \geqslant t\alpha) \leqslant \frac{E[e^{sX}]}{e^{st\alpha}}$

by Markov's inequality. Since $E[e^{sX}] = e^{\alpha(e^{s}-1)}$, we have:

$P(X > t\alpha ) \leqslant \frac{e^{\alpha(e^{s}-1)}}{e^{st\alpha}} = e^{\alpha(e^{s}-1)-st\alpha}$

Maximizing this bound is equivalent to maximizing $\alpha(e^{s}-1)-st\alpha$. And it is obvious that maximizing $\alpha(e^{s}-1)-st\alpha$ is equivalent to maximizing $f(s) = e^{s}-st$ since $\alpha > 0$.

$f\prime(s) = e^{s} - t$

$f\prime\prime(s) = e^{s}$

Solve $f\prime(s) = 0$, we have $s = \ln{t}$. And $f\prime\prime(\ln{t}) = t > 0$. So $s = \ln{t}$ maximizes $f(s)$.

$P(X > t\alpha ) \leqslant \frac{e^{\alpha(t-1)}}{t^{t\alpha}} = (\frac{e^{\alpha}}{t^{\alpha}})^t e^{-\alpha} $

Now let's compare $\frac{e^{\alpha}}{t^{\alpha}}$ with $\alpha \frac{e}{t}$. When $t \geqslant 3$, we have $\frac{e^{\alpha}}{t^{\alpha}} < \alpha \frac{e}{t}$.

When $t= 2$, we have $(\frac{e}{2})^\alpha$ and $\alpha \frac{e}{2}$. When $\alpha = 10$, we have $(\frac{e}{2})^\alpha = 21.51022050274092$ and
$\alpha \frac{e}{2} = 13.591409142295225 $. When $\alpha = 20$, we have
$(\frac{e}{2})^\alpha = 462.68958607653593$ and $\alpha \frac{e}{2} = 27.18281828459045$. So when $t = 2$, $\frac{e^{\alpha}}{t^{\alpha}} < \alpha \frac{e}{t}$ is not true.

By the above discussion, we can prove $P(X > t\alpha ) \leqslant (\alpha \frac{e}{t})^{t} e^{-\alpha}$ for $t \geqslant 3$. But we can't prove the $t = 2$ case.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the statement you reproduced? I.e., what exactly is the Poisson r.v. there?

Comment: @A.S. The link is the web site for the book not book itself.

Comment: @A.S. I will edit my question to give enough background so that you can have a try.

Comment: This might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem

Comment: The fact that, if $X_a$ is Poisson with parameter $a$, then $P(|X_a-a|\geqslant xa)\to0$ when $a\to\infty$, for every fixed positive $x$, is a consequence of Bienaymé-Chebychev inequality since $X_a$ has variance $a$ hence this probability is at most $a/(xa)^2=1/(x^2a)\to0$. As usual, the probability is exponentially small rather than of order $1/a$ (and more refined arguments allow to show this), but the "variance" approach suffices to conclude.

Comment: The question was modified and now seems to ask how to bound $P(X_a\geqslant xa)$ for $x>1$ fixed, when $a\to\infty$. The standard approach is to optimize the exponential bound $P(X_a\geqslant xa)\leqslant e^{-sxa}E(e^{sX_a})$ over $s>0$. Note that $E(e^{sX_a})=\exp(a(e^s-1))$ hence one wants to minimize $a(e^s-1)-sxa$, which happens when $e^s=x$, then the upper bound reads $$P(X_a\geqslant xa)\leqslant x^{-xa}e^{a(x-1)}=(e^x/(x^xe))^a.$$

Comment: @Rol, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem explains Poisson approximation for binomial distribution not $(\alpha\text{ }e/t)^t e^{-\alpha}$.

Comment: Did's bound is correct (and stronger than yours) but we can do a little better asymptotically: $$P(X_a=at+i)=P(X_{at}=at+i)\frac {P(X_a=at+i)}{P(X_{at}=at+i)}\sim (2\pi at)^{-1/2}\frac{e^{at}}{e^at^{at}}t^{-i}$$ hence

$$P(X_a\ge at)\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi at}}\frac {t}{t-1}\left(\frac e t\right)^{at}e^{-a}=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi a}}\frac {\sqrt t}{t-1}\left( e^{t-1-t\log t}\right)^a$$ and $t-1-t\log t\sim-\frac 1 2(t-1)^2$ for $t\to 1^{+}$

Comment: @Did, I guess that your comment is the right answer to my question. But the mathematics knowledge involved is beyond my reach. Can you explain why $P(X_a \geqslant xa) \leqslant e^{-sxa} E(e^{sX_{a}})$ holds?

Comment: @JingguoYao For $s > 0$, $\{ X_a \geq xa \} = \{ sX_a \geq sxa \}= \{ e^{sX_a} \geq e^{sxa} \}$, so $$\mathbb{P}\{ X_a \geq xa \} \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{sX_a}]}{e^{sxa}}$$ by Markov's inequality. (This is the usual way Chernoff/Hoeffding bounds are proven). The first two equalities hold because $x\mapsto sx$ and $x\mapsto e^x$ are increasing.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

I've been spending hours thinking about the same problem!

It turns out that the formula $(\alpha e/t)^t e^{-\alpha}$ is incorrect. The correct formula is $(e/t)^{\alpha t}e^{-\alpha}$.

The correction is posted on the textbook website: [Errata](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/errata/errata-printing11.php).